# How to hide rich:modalPanel on Ajax response in JSF

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I am using jsf reach faces in one application. I am using rich:modalPanel for popup reading some details and submitting tha panel using a4j command button after response from server I want to hide the  modalPanel but don't know how to,

I am still trying for the solution, Any help Please

The code of rich modalPanel is something like this.

```
<rich:modalPanel  id="panelID" minHeight="200" minWidth="450" height="200" width="500">
<a4j:commandButton reRender="sampleID" action="#{SomeTestAction}" image="sample-button.gif"/> 
</rich:modalPanel>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is easy, you can write:

```
**UPDATED**
```

This solution is better, because you don't need javaScript.

```
<a4j:commandButton reRender="sampleID" action="#{SomeTestAction}" image="sample-button.gif">
      <rich:componentControl for="panelId" operation="hide" event="onclick" />
 </a4j:commandButton>
```

Or with javaScript

```
<a4j:commandButton reRender="sampleID" action="#{SomeTestAction}" image="sample-button.gif" oncomplete="javascript:Richfaces.hideModalPanel('panelId');"/>
```

Or you can submit form, and popup disappear.

```
<a4j:commandButton reRender="sampleID" action="#{SomeTestAction}" image="sample-button.gif" oncomplete="document.getElementById('Id_form').submit();"/>:
```

Where "`Id_form`" - is id of the form where `<rich:modalPanel>` was shown.

Comment: is it possible to close it, from a normal javascript file? (i want to make different thinks by an `onmaskclick` but at the end it should be closed